# Is there a popup function in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

As the title says, does Bootstrap 3 supports popup function by default and if yes, how is it activated?

I'm talking about a normal popup when user clicks on image/link a new windoes shows up displaying youtube link/etc.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for the modal (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) or popover (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers)?

Comment: When you say "a new window shows up" that means opening another browser window.  That's not a function of Bootstrap. Use the window.open() function in JavaScript to do that.  Don't expect us to do your Googling for you; go look up the window.open() function.

Answer (score 1):

As mentiond above, bootstrap does not support opening a new browser window. You can achieve this simply by using javascript:

**Javascript**

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
   window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");
}
</script>
```

See: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

**Bootstrap Modal**

If you want a nice popup, but not a new window, try using bootstraps modal:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

When you use this, don't forget to include `bootstrap.js`

See: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

**HTML**

And there allways is the html option for opening a new window :)

```
<a href="www.yoururl.com" target="_blank">Your link</a>
```

If this doens't answer your question, please clarify your definition of a popup...